# Does PostgreSQL support PMML

Tags: postgresql, pmml

I couldn't find any reference that PostgreSQL db supports [PMML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) using a search engine. I was wondering if anyone had any luck with this. I would like to deploy a Random Forest model that is built in R in PostgreSQL (I'm aware of other work arounds - but want to get an answer for this question before I go down the other route).

Answer (score 1):

From my own reading, PostgreSQL doesn't directly support PMML, however if you use JPMML it integrates seamlessly with PostgreSQL.  Its library is opensource and extensive.

https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support.  However with the XML support, the extensible stored procedure language handlers, and such it shouldn't be too hard to implement as an add-on (or perhaps an extension).

I don't foresee PMML support coming built into PostgreSQL in the near to moderate future so you would do best to either implement it yourself or go another route.